# Why does jslint shout at me?

Tags: jslint

My code is the following (also available at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YcAqA/)):

```
$button = $('<button />', {
    text: 'my button',
    class: 'button'
});
```

The jslint error message is:

```
Problem at line 3 character 5: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'class' (a reserved word).
class: 'button'
```

Comment: I think it's complaining that class is a reserved keyword, so to use it you might need quotation marks to distinguish it from the keyword. But not sure...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Class is a reserved word for Javascript 2.0](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/classes.html), thus you should not use it as a key in an object without putting it between quotes to mark it as a string.

Comment: And `class: "myString"` to `'class': 'myString'` works.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/qv46A/)